# type.IsInterface return false for interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, rhino-mocks

I have a method that returns `propertyInfo` for given type. I am calling this method with an object of interface but `type.IsInterface` is returning false.

```
public IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetProperties(Type type)
{
    if (!type.IsInterface)
        return type.GetProperties();

    return (new Type[] { type })
           .Concat(type.GetInterfaces())
           .SelectMany(i => i.GetProperties());

}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

I am using rhino mock to generate interface mock that is passing to this function.

Here is the code, how I m calling this function...

```
var info = GetProperties(pCache.Data.GetType())
```

in this, Data is an object of `IdataCache.`

Comment: Show the code where you call this method.

Comment: You have an instance (`pCache.Data`). That is an object, an instance of a class (you can't create an instance of an interface). [`GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx) returns this class type. You can't call `GetType` on anything and it will return an interface. You can call your method like `GetProperties(typeof(IFoo))` that will pass the interface to the method. In that case `IsInterface` will return true.

Comment: Then how can I get the type of interface.

Comment: Surprisingly to get type of something you should use `typeof` - i.e. `typeof(IEnumerable).IsInterface` is true.

Comment: You already do that in GetProperties(), but, is type.GetProperties not sufficient? This will return the properties declared by the concrete type which contains all the properties defined by all the implemented interfaces.

Comment: got it. I need to update the calling code with GetProperties(typeof(IDataCache))

Comment: GetProperties() gives me propertiesInfo, when I actually run the application. but in unit testing, when I mock interface object, GetProperties() given me an empty list of properties.

Answer (score 2):

PCache.Data is an instance of pCache.Data.GetType(), and it's type cannot be an interface and must be a concrete type.

pCache.Data.GetType() will always return the type of the instance, and if it is IdataCache then IdataCache is a concrete type